# Viewpager2 + RecyclerView Scroll Issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I have a viewpager2 with TabLayout which hosts fragments that contain a vertical RecyclerView as shown in [the GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52fCn.gif)
Sometimes when I scroll to top or bottom the ViewPager swipe occurs and changes tab. I wrapped my RecyclerView inside `NestedScrollableHost` class, however, it does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered this particular problem, but had some other bugs when using viewpager2. You could try changing to the oryginal viewpager.

Comment: No, I use in my apps all the time. If you want to extend a viewpager functionalities, you can only use viewpager not viewpager2. I'll give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this behavior with ViewPager2. As of now, the only way to solve is to use original ViewPager.